# "우리 사랑하지 말아요" Translation of lyrics

Tags: korean-to-english

I'm trying to learn/understand the [lyrics](https://gasazip.com/view.html?no=586794) of this song "[우리 사랑하지 말아요](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jTo6hTZmiQ)", but I don't understand the end of this line:

> 사실 조금은 두려운 거야

Could some nice person help me? :)

I know that the verb to be afraid is 두렵다, and that "거야" is one of the future tense conjugations, but I don't understand why this sentence would be in the future or why the 운 comes after 두려.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi - I couldn't see the actual line you meant, so I added what I hope is the right one.

Comment: that's not future tense

Answer (score 1):

Here is a translation of the song that looks pretty accurate

https://ilyricsbuzz.com/2015/08/bigbang-lets-not-fall-in-love-lyrics.html

> 우리 사랑하지 말아요 아직은 잘 모르잖아요
>   사실 조금은 두려운 거야 그대 미안해요
>   우리 약속하지 말아요 내일은 또 모르잖아요
>   하지만 이 말 만은 진심이야 그대 좋아해요
>
> Let’s not fall in love, we don’t know each other very well yet
>   Actually, I’m a little scared, I’m sorry
>   Let’s not make promises, you never know when tomorrow comes
>   But I really mean it when I say I like you

-거야 is not necessarily future tense and 두려운 actually indicates this is not future tense

-거야 is most likely a more shortened informal version of 거예요

See here:

https://www.italki.com/question/198655?hl=ko

> 뭐하는 거야 = short for 뭐하는 것이야 (or 뭐하고 있는 것이야 in this case) 것 is a
>   pronoun, used like 이것, 저것, 그것.

https://www.koreanclass101.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2460
https://www.reddit.com/r/Korean/comments/4pqyc6/%E3%84%B4_%EA%B1%B0%EC%97%90%EC%9A%94_how_do_you_use_this_naturally/